# Second Order Methods for conservation laws

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the scalar conservation law $u_t+f(u)_x=0.$
I understand that [Lax-Wendroff scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Wendroff_method) is second order accurate, because of the way it is derived using Taylor series. However since this scheme is not [TVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_diminishing) there are various methods obtained from Lax-Wendroff scheme by introducing a correction term/Limiters. For example minmod, superbee, van Leer etc.

Now I have the following doubts:

1. Are these schemes second order accurate always? If so how to prove?
2. How to prove that these schemes converge to Kruzkov entropy solutions? (They are not monotone anymore!! So the standard monotone argument may not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, these slope- or flux-limiter schemes are not second-order accurate anymore. In fact, their order of accuracy measured numerically is rather around 1.6-1.8. This becomes obvious after realising that they are a kind of compromise between first-order and second-order schemes, see e.g. the 2002 book by R.J. LeVeque.

For the second part, I may find some special cases where this property is proven in literature. **To be updated.**